# Normalize data in a Matrix into deciles

Tags: matlab

I try to normalize the data for each row of Matrix A into deciles.

Matrix A looks like:

```
[.01 .02 .03 .04 .05;
 1 2 3 4 5;
 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000];
```

how to normalize the first row into deciles, then the second row...till the last row? without using 'for/while'?

The output would be like:

```
[2 3 6 8 10;
 2 3 6 8 10;
 2 3 6 8 10];
```

Look for a script. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a question or are you just looking for someone to do this for you?

Comment: It is a question. I don't know whether a convenient formula is available, and I am looking for an easy way to normalize the data..Thanks!

Comment: @user1205030, what kind of data? A 1D array of numbers, and you want to put them into 10 bins based on magnitude? Maybe a small example of your data would be helpful.

Comment: It is 2D. (:,1) are dates, (1,2:end) are data to be normalized.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Either wait for someone cleverer than I am (you won't have to wait too long) or provide a clear example of the output you want from a function which takes rand(4,5) as input.

Comment: thx. I have added an example, does it make sense?

Comment: I see that your clarification has brought forth an answer. I hope it is correct and useful.

Comment: How on earth 1 2 3 4 5 became 2 3 6 8 10?!\

Comment: By normalize I mean the data in the top decile get a score of 10, those in the second best decile have a value of 9, and the bottom 10% will get a score of 1.

Comment: Also cross posted: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/matlab-how-to-normalize-data-into-deciles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce something similar to what you are asking for (using `tiedrank` from the Statistics toolbox):

```
f = @(x,i) tiedrank(x)*10/numel(x);
bsxfun(f,x',ones(1,3))'
```

be careful with the rounding and breaks though, you would likely need to adjust the last line in general.

Also: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296568/matlab-normalize-data-into-deciles

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sortrows command to sort a matrix according to a particular column.  From there, if n is the length of your matrix, just assign a value of 1 for matrix(1:n/10,i), 2 for matrix(n/10+1:2*n/10), etc. (obviously with some rounding to be done if n/10 isn't an integer).

Comment: Thanks. I thought a formula would make the work easier. Any suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) in combination with [QUANTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/quantile.html) function from Statistical toolbox to generate the edges:

```
x = randn(20,1);
q = quantile(x,0:0.1:1);
[~,xqnorm] = histc(x,q);
```

**EDIT**: HISTC does not include the value equal to the right edge of a bin. Because of this `max(x)` will not be assigned to the 10th bin, but to the extra (11-th) bin. To avoid it you can increase the largest edge a little bit (insert this line before histc call):

```
q(end) = q(end)+0.1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not too sure.  But I think I have some snippets that go in the right direction.

Say we always call your matrix data

```
 data  = rand(3,4)
```

You get the max of every row with

```
 m_val = max(data,2)
```

You can build a matrix

```
 mat = diag( 10./ m_val )
```

If you calculate

```
 res = mat * data
```

It should have the properties as I understand.

---

Maybe another usefull snippet

```
 [a,b] = sort(vec)
```

b holds the indices from the sort - so you could line wise create a matrix from your original data. Then the previous snippets.

Comment: This would not compute the deciles from the empirical distribution. This simply scales each row by the row max.

Comment: Aha this wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: Well that wasn't my question, but it seems like he is asking about computing deciles. What your answer does is (1) estimate the upper bound by the sample max (this is a biased estimate, and assumes that the distribution is uniform over the range), (2) assume that the lower bound is zero, and (3) compute "quantiles" with respect to the estimated distribution.

Comment: My bad - it did work on the example - then I stopped reading :)

Comment: By the way - since you mention it. Shouldn't the first row of the original example be always mapped to 0? My statistics is a bit rusty...